# can a site hosted on meteor.com use an external mongoDB?

Tags: deployment, meteor

I don't think they can, and a quick check with

MONGO_URL=mongodb://XXX meteor deploy BBB.meteor.com

seems to spin up a new database. if anyone can confirm if this is not possible, or if there's some other method... thanks!

Comment: not sure about mongo..but for all major dbs you could..

Comment: steve - what do you mean? this question is about meteorJS.

Comment: oh. I thought you are asking if you can use an external DB that's not hosted by your host provider

Comment: what do you mean? You supplied the MONGO_URL environment variable to the process that sends data to a remote server? How do you expect it to work? If you want the app to be connected to a remote mongo while running on meteor.com, you can set the variable in the code: `process.env.MONGO_URL='blabla'`